# Ошибка в программе "Для нестатического поля " Settings.AdventureWorksConnectionString" требуется ссылка на объект"

Tags: c#

Ошибка в программе "Для нестатического поля " Settings.AdventureWorksConnectionString" требуется ссылка на объект". 
Код класса DatabaseConnection:

```
class DatabaseConnection
    {
        private ConnectionStringSettings myConnectionString;
        private SqlConnection mySqlConnection;
        private SqlCommand mySqlCommand;

        public DatabaseConnection()
        {
            myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Properties.Settings.AdventureWorksConnectionString];
            mySqlConnection = new
            SqlConnection(myConnectionString.ConnectionString);
            mySqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
}
}
```

Код Settings:

```
namespace SalesApplication.Properties {

    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "16.4.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.ConnectionString)]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True")]
        public string AdventureWorksConnectionString {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["AdventureWorksConnectionString"]));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Если сделать метод статическим, то ключевое слово this не получится использовать в нем.

Comment: У вас же есть в классе `Default`.

Comment: Такое обращение `Properties.Settings.AdventureWorksConnectionString` подразумевает, что `AdventureWorksConnectionString` является статичным, т.к. вызывается напрямую из класса `Settings`. Однако, в `Settings` уже есть статичное поле-инстанции объекта `Default` и тогда через него можно сделать обращение: `Properties.Settings.Default.AdventureWorksConnectionString`